# convert varchar to decimal Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, type-conversion

I would like to convert varchar to decimal value

When I use

```
try_cast(unitPrice as decimal) as price_value
```

I receive error **Failed to output to file. Value is not a number: java.lang.String**

However when i use

```
try_cast(unitPrice as integer ) as price_value
```

I receive null values for decimal values

What is causing this error ?

Comment: There is no `try_cast` in Oracle. And `Value is not a number: java.lang.String` is not an Oracle error message either (they all start with `ORA-`)

Answer (score 2):

Oracle has the following numeric data types:

{ NUMBER [ (precision [, scale ]) ]
| FLOAT [ (precision) ]
| BINARY_FLOAT
| BINARY_DOUBLE
}

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28285/sqlqr06.htm#g999425

So you should probably try something like

```
cast(unitPrice as float) as price_value
```

Comment: Not a good idea to use floats for money. number would be a wiser choice

Comment: Possibly. Without knowing the wider context it is impossible to say in this case. There are plenty of times that things can have a monetary value of < 0.01 or whatever the lowest unit of currency is in a country. But if the value being sorted is a retail price, for example, then you would be correct.

Comment: Thank you for your answer that clarifies a lot !